# How to deobfuscate Java stacktrace in Flutter app with Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, crashlytics

In my firebase console i can see the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Bad state: Cannot add event after closing. Error thrown null.
       at _StreamController.add(_StreamController.java:595)
       at _Rb.add(_Rb.java:867)
       at ._Zj(.java:1434)
       at _Fc.runUnary(_Fc.java:1335)
       at _Fc.fRa(_Fc.java:1244)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._ieb(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:341)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._add(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:271)
       at _hc._add(_hc.java:123)
       at _kc._Veb(_kc.java:253)
       at _hc._Veb(_hc.java:153)
       at ._Zj(.java:1434)
       at _Fc.runUnary(_Fc.java:1335)
       at _Fc.fRa(_Fc.java:1244)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._ieb(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:341)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._add(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:271)
       at _hc._add(_hc.java:123)
       at _jc._Veb(_jc.java:218)
       at _hc._Veb(_hc.java:153)
       at ._Zj(.java:1434)
       at _Fc.runUnary(_Fc.java:1335)
       at _Fc.fRa(_Fc.java:1244)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._ieb(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:341)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._add(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:271)
       at _hc._add(_hc.java:123)
       at _jc._Veb(_jc.java:218)
       at _hc._Veb(_hc.java:153)
       at ._Zj(.java:1434)
       at _Fc.runUnary(_Fc.java:1335)
       at _Fc.fRa(_Fc.java:1244)
       at _BufferingStreamSubscription._ieb(_BufferingStreamSubscription.java:341)
       at _Yb.zdb(_Yb.java:591)
       at _bc.pdb(_bc.java:706)
       at _Wb.tdb.<fn>(tdb.java:663)
       at ._Wj(.java:1418)
       at _Fc.oRa(_Fc.java:1328)
       at _Fc.eRa(_Fc.java:1236)
       at _Fc.jRa.<fn>(jRa.java:1276)
       at ._Wj(.java:1426)
       at _Fc.oRa(_Fc.java:1328)
       at _Fc.eRa(_Fc.java:1236)
       at _Fc.jRa.<fn>(jRa.java:1276)
       at ._yj(.java:40)
       at ._zj(.java:49)
```

I'm using the latest Firebase pub (from `pubspec.lock`):

```
firebase_crashlytics:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: firebase_crashlytics
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.8.2"
  firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.2.8"
```

What can i do to get a readable stacktrace?

PS. Also it's very confusing as the issue seem to happen in Dart code, but i can see Java files in stacktrace..

PPS. I do have configured android project for obfuscation as follows:

```
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.googleplaySigningConfig

            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib"
            }

            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics recently [added support](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#crashlytics-flutter-symbolication-support) for Flutter applications built with the `--split-debug-info` and `--obfuscate`.

If you were building the app with these parameters, try upgrading the Crashlytics SDK to the latest version.